# Remove an item from "menu local task"

Tags: routes

I need to remove "Create new account" from the tabs on `/user` page.

I was suggested to use `hook_menu`, but:

- It seems that `hook_menu` can only add, not remove items.
- `hook_menu` does not work for me as I described in [Why my hook_menu does not work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60959/why-my-hook-menu-does-not-work)

Further: I've found that there is also `hook_menu_alter` hook. But it does not work for me also. I created the following function for testing:

```
function cleanetica_advanced_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['user'] = array(
       'title' => 'blogs',
       'description' => 'Listing of blogs.',
       #'page callback' => 'blog_page',
       'access arguments' => array('access content'),
       'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK
     );
    //$items = array();
}
```

I see no changes in `/user` page after I have added this function into the module,

Comment: You are resetting the existing array!!! (and posting many questions for a single problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the registration feature and you need to just remove the link from the default tab, then use menu_alter hook.

```
function modulename_menu_alter(&$item) {
// Hide the "Create new account" tab
$item['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

Comment: This does not help. (Yes, I've cleaned the caches.)

Comment: Well no, it works! I've just made a spelling error in PHP,

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove "Create new account" from the tabs on /user page.

Sounds like you just need to disable the ability for users to create their own account.

There's a config setting at:

**Admin > Config > Account Settings**  *"Who can register accounts" =
 "Administrators only"*

[image: Account settings]

Comment: No, users should be able to create account from some other pages of the site

Comment: You didn't state that in your question.